# Can't connect to Wireless router from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a wireless router from which:
- I can connect from one laptop running Windows XP.
- I cannot connect from another laptop running Windows 7

We have put the same settings on both laptops: the name of the wirless network,  WPA2, the password.

But the Windows 7 laptop gets an error message ("Eingeschränkter Zugriff" in German, which I think means "partly functional").

Also the connection used to work on the Windows 7 laptop. Nothing was manually changed. And suddenly the connection did not work anymore.

Any help is most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed after we uninstalled the Firewall software.

It seems the Firewall setting schanged, perhaps after 3 months that we had the laptop (some free period expiration or something) which caused the wireless network problem...

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have meant "Limited Connectivity" If you go to the Network and Sharing Center:

Start > Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center

You will then be able to see an exclamation mark or red cross on the connectivity section.

Just simply click the icon and it will look for problems and attempt to fix them.

Also make sure you aren't assigning the same IP address to both laptops as then it will cause a conflict. Let DHCP handle the address giving.